# Count the number of elements in pandas df

Tags: pandas

| Person | numbers | tries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tina | [1,5,4,5] | 4 |
| rina | [3,5,4,5,6] | 5 |

I want to create a new column tries as above .
In the tries column it should be the no.of elements from numbers column.
when we give str.split it gives error as the numbers column each element is of int type and after that even if change the numbers column to type str it will give the same error tht list doesnt have split .

Is there any other way to do it .

Comment: `df['tries'] = df['numbers'].str.len()`